# swift protocol with default value

Tags: swift, swift4, protocols

I am practicing swift protocols by rewriting a custom tableview implementation.

```
protocol PreviewModuleViewDataSource {
    func previewModuleView(_ moduleView: PreviewModuleView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    func previewModuleView(_ moduleView: PreviewModuleView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> PreviewModuleViewItem
}
```

I have the protocol for number of items in section and "cell for item" at index path..

Then I extend my protocol like so:

```
func previewModuleView(_ moduleView: PreviewModuleView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func previewModuleView(_ moduleView: PreviewModuleView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> PreviewModuleViewItem {

        let item = PreviewModuleViewItem()
        item.image = UIImage(named: "ItunesArtwork")

        return item

    }
```

My question is how can I actually get the value of "dataSource.count" in my core class which will use the data?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to use the value returned from `func previewModuleView(_ moduleView: PreviewModuleView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int` within the `PreviewModuleView` object?

```
protocol PreviewModuleViewDataSource: class {
    func previewModuleView(_ moduleView: PreviewModuleView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    func previewModuleView(_ moduleView: PreviewModuleView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> PreviewModuleViewItem
}

class PreviewModuleView {
    weak var dataSource: PreviewModuleViewDataSource?

    func useValueExample() {
        if let numberOfItems = dataSource?.previewModuleView(self, numberOfItemsInSection: 0) {
            print("Number of items in section 0 = \(numberOfItems)")
        }
    }
}
```

When you are using a table view, for example, you have to assign your View Controller as the data source. So you need a data source variable to assign the delegate to. And when you want to access the number of items in a section you would call that function on the data source.

In this example, I changed the protocol to a `class` protocol and made the data source variable weak, something I would recommend.